# I am getting error even after successful output in angular 2 project. Why So?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have create a project in angular (version 2.1.0) in visual studio 2017.
Everything is working fine, just I am getting error as below:

`EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'`

Total 5 errors are coming up in console but their is not issue in code while running.

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { AboutComponent } from './demo/about.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {
        path: 'Home',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'Index',
                component: AppComponent
            },

            //{
            //    path: 'About',
            //    component: AboutComponent
            //}
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: AppComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
// Add the RxJS Observable operators we need in this app.
import './js/ng/rxjs-operators';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'demo-tag',
    templateUrl: './demo/demo-list.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }
    name = 'First Angular 2 Application';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**demo-list.html** (it is in app - demo - demo-list.html)

```
<div>This is demo list page</div>
```

Comment: can you show the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router outlet is never rendered since you are not referencing the app.component.html from anywhere. I believe you should NOT be using

```
templateUrl: './demo/demo-list.html'
```

but

```
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
```

Comment: I have used app.component.html also at that place but not working.

Comment: I sugget you make a stackblitz sample so one can actually see what you have done and find the issues. But here i am pretty sure that you have made some small mistakes (have <router-outlet> in the index.html page or any default document you may have) which makes angular wonder where to render the AppComponent.

Comment: with this change it is working but don't know why I have changed this earlier and it is not working but anyways it is working now thanks.